# Javascript - Prototype - Ignore <li style: display none;> <inputs> verify rest of inputs are not empty and submit. Can this be possible?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have no idea on how to do this so here it goes. What I need is to be able to just validate for empty fields the  with no display none;. I am using prototype.

```
new.onclick = function() {
if (document.getElementById("ticket").style.display !== "none" &&
    document.getElementsByTagName("input").length === 0) {
          alert('need to have something here');      
    }
     alert('need here');      
  };
```

Comment: this '`new.onclick`' is a little weird. The `if` etc. seems legit. Further, add some html maybe? (From the element that needs to invoke this function)

Comment: can you post more of your code so that we can understand more of the context?

Comment: What is `new`? Technically it is a keyword and invalid as an identifier, but you seem to use it as a variable.

Comment: What is `empty fields the with no display none;.`? Seems like some HTML markup was skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use your if statement this way:

```
if (document.getElementById("ticket").style.display !== "none" || document.getElementsByTagName("input").length === 0)
```

so it will be true if no input is added to the DOM or ticket is display: none

anyway if you dont have an Element with ID ticket, your script will be abortet

```
if(document.getElementById("ticket") != null) {
...
}
```